# iTunes Match can no longer download anything on iPhone

Tags: itunes, ios, iphone, itunes-match

I am able to stream songs but cannot download and store them. This goes for any song in my library whether purchased, matched, or uploaded and whether Wi-Fi or LTE.

This has become a large issue as I have recently begun taking the metro to work at a new job and cannot stream for most of the time underground. My data usage has increased to near the throttling limit during last month and that's been a contributing factor.

Even worse, the songs actually are downloading completely but then never adding to the local library and then giving me an individual popup message for each song saying it failed. So more data usage occurs for nothing.

I've tried disabling/reenabling match on both my phone and the MacBook, and countless other settings adjustments but nothing's worked so far.

**Update:** Discovered today that songs I have streamed do remain on the device after. When you shut off the cell&wifi networks the cloud-only songs are greeted out so this was easy enough to test.  Downloading (and not streaming) still does not actually retrieve the song in the music player, however.

<sup>32 GB iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1 jailbroken</sup>
<sup>I realise the word "jailbroken" very well may be the source of my troubles but I'd like to try some other options first before upgrading to see if this fixes the issue.  Especially because it had been working fine until recently while jailbroken, and I've seen reports of the same exact issue on phones running stock iOS 7 also.</sup>